# !empty record show in first order in cake php

Tags: sorting, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have a retrieved restaurant list. when the restaurant menu is empty that restaurant showed in last order.. what i do.. can you help..

My Query is :

```
$restaurantList = $this->Restaurants->find('all', [
            'conditions' => $conditions,
            'contain' => [
                'DeliveryLocations' => [
                    'conditions' => $areaLocationConditions,
                ],
                'RestaurantMenus' => [
                    'conditions' => [
                        'RestaurantMenus.status' => 1,
                        'RestaurantMenus.delete_status' => 'N'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'limit' => 5,
            'order' => 'Restaurants.id DESC'
        ])->hydrate(false)->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

by implementing CounterCache
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html and order by cache results.

More complex:

by using Case statements

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#case-statements

select 'has_menus' if restuarant has menus then 1 else 0

order by that results